# This is related to npm not being able to find a file. I'm trying to run a react native project , but im getting this error

Tags: react-native, npm

I am a react native beginner.  I got this error while trying to run a RN project.

```
C:\Users\Devesh Shukla\Documents\[FreeCourseSite.com] Udemy - The Complete React Native + Hooks Course [2020 Edition]\1. Getting Started\3.1 rn-starter>npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Devesh Shukla\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Devesh Shukla\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Devesh Shukla\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-30T11_00_57_103Z-debug.log

C:\Users\Devesh Shukla\Documents\[FreeCourseSite.com] Udemy - The Complete React Native + Hooks Course [2020 Edition]\1. Getting Started\3.1 rn-starter>
```

i just ran `npm start` and i got this error.

PS: I've update npm.

Comment: You should run your project like this: `react-native run-android` for android and `react-native run-ios` for ios

Comment: not working  . im getting this   ``` 'react-native' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. ```